# How do I position one image overlaid by another image?

Tags: html, css

I need to position elements and receive like in attached image

[image]

I have a page where all elements are inside MainDiv. There are 2 images.

I would wondering if somebody showed my html + css should be.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

you can accomplish this the following way: 
 assign the background image as background to the main div

```
background: url(some/url/to/image) no-repeat scroll top right transparent;
```

then add a normal image element inside that div and position it absolute with the folllowing css

```
right: 0;
bottom:0;
position: absolute;
```

make sure the main div has position set to relative

Comment: do you mean that I should align my background image top and use padding left 200 ?

Comment: I managed to overlay images but my Div Menu moved at the page top and it is located under my background image. Before overlaying image div menu was ok. How to fix menu div?

Answer (score 2):

A possible way would be to set the position of the overlayed image to absolute:

```
#overlayImage{
  position:absolute;
  right:0px;
  bottom:0px;
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
}
```

Important is, that the position of the main div is not "static".

```
<div id="main_div">
  <div id="other div"> </di>
  <div id="overlayImage"> </div>
</div
```

Comment: It should be position:relative; instead.

Comment: I didn't get about position of the main div is not "static". What it should be?

Comment: `#main_div` should be `position: relative;` otherwise `#overlayImage` will align its bottom and right with the body.

Comment: I did like below, bit now mu Div Menu has moved at the page top. How to return it back? <div id="main" style="background: url(Content/img/MainContent.jpg) no-repeat scroll top right transparent; position: relative">
            <div id="djInfo">
               <img alt="Site background" src="/Content/img/MainContent.jpg" runat="server" /> 
               <img alt="Site background" src="/Content/img/DjPhoto.png" runat="server" class="overlayImg"/> 
            </div>
              @RenderBody()
           <div id="footer">
                <div id="menucontainer">
                    <ul>